# Facebook mail notifier

Tags: email, facebook

I would like to have an application which can send me an email every time when I get message or poke. But I want to get full unread message.  Let me explain:

Someone sent me:

> Hey!
>   Today is beautiful day!

And I want to get mail like:

> You got message from xyz:
>   Hey!
>   Today is beautiful day!

Facebook has this feature, but it doesn't work well, sometimes it is perfect, but rarely.